# taskkill window spaces in its title name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run taskkill on a console window that has spaces in it's title.
How can I pass this window title to taskkill.
I have tried the following:

```
taskkill /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq Administrator: My Window Title"
```

Comment: I created a process using `start "Administrator: My Window Title" CMD` and your exact command works fine on my Vista machine.

Comment: Same as dbenham, I'm on Win7, what error do you get? Have you tried `/f`?

Comment: In case of running cmd.exe through Administrator permission, resulted cmd window title format is "<Administrator:><2 spaces><title that you specified>".

Comment: Be careful to the <2 spaces>. So, in your case, you should use the title name like this, "WINDOWTITLE eq Administrator:[ ][ ]My Window Title"

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I've had similar problems, but found out a little bit more.

### Problem

I have been trying to close a CMD window (run as administrator) which has set its own window title.  So, run CMD as administrator and type:

```
title CMD with custom title
```

After much faffing, the following command showed me that setting the window title puts a leading space in front of the title!  (No idea why.)

```
c:\>tasklist /V /FI "WindowTitle eq Administrator*"

Image Name  PID Session Name Session# Mem Usage Status  User Name       CPU Time Window Title
========== ==== ============ ======== ========= ======= =============== ======== =====================================
cmd.exe    4304 Console             1   2,492 K Running MACHINE\My Name  0:00:00 Administrator:  CMD with custom title
                                                                                               
(scroll )                                                                               extra space
```

---

### Solution

So to kill the process:

```
taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq  Administrator:  CMD with custom title" /T
                                               
                                             bingo
```

- `/F` - use the force.
- `/T` - kill child-processes.

If you're banging your head in a similar fashion, I recommend using `tasklist` to poke around inside the process properties to make sure you're getting your filters right.  This ballache brought to you by Windows 8.

*Note:* if the title contains quotation marks, just escape the nested ones:

```
title "CMD with custom title"

taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq  Administrator:  \"CMD with custom title\"" /T
```

Comment: Same thing here on Windows 7. I never would have guessed it, thanks a bunch!

Comment: I had this problem and sometimes title was with and extra space and sometimes no. I solved this simply executing two lines -> one with extra space and one without, ensuring working with both cases.

Answer (score 9):

The trick is to name the cmd process and then kill it by calling the name you have given:
The following is starting 6 parallel processes and you can kill any one of choice.

```
start "cmd001" cmd.exe
start "cmd002" cmd.exe
start "cmd003" cmd.exe
start "cmd004" cmd.exe
start "cmd005" cmd.exe
start "cmd 006" cmd.exe
```

:: kill the process you want, e.g. cmd005

```
taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq cmd005" /T
```

:: kill a process which has a SPACE in its name, e.g. cmd 006

```
taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq cmd 006" /T
```

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: @Stephan I have edited it. you could see it above with space.

Comment: @Shoresh, without the flags `/F` & `/T`, this looks the same as the command in the question; is your answer to use those flags to get it to work?

Comment: This helped me a lot because it also explains how to start a program with a specific window title.

Comment: Wonderful,  has solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I guess this task run on your windows server . If the title  includes "Administrator : "  you can not kill the task via WindowTitle equal.

You should use this : This is my killer.bat.  SEARCH_PARAMETER = WHAT TITLE YOU WANNA KILL

```
@echo off
            for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('
tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v /fo:csv /nh 
^| findstr /r /c:".*SEARCH_PARAMETER[^,]*$" ') do taskkill /pid %%a
```

Answer (score 1):

taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq Apache 8184"

Comment: Did you mean to post this?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer (4yo), but a good way to kill a process when you know only a part of the process name is using the *old* [`WMIC`](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tgp/scsadmins/winadmin/WMIC_Queries.txt).
Here's an example to `find` and `kill` a process named `"Administrator: My Window Title"`:

```
WMIC PROCESS WHERE "NAME LIKE '%Administrator: My Window Title%'" CALL TERMINATE
```

Comment: Nice! Of the many proposed solutions out there, this was my silver bullet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was starting cmd shell windows using AutoIt and the tip about using tasklist really helped. I already tried the double spaces but AutoIt's Run() command created the cmd.exe shell in a manner that tasklist/taskkill could not see the window title.

If I used a loop or AutoIt's WinKill()/WinClose() with the window title for the cmd prompt then AutoIt itself could close the window but my cmd prompt bat files only saw c:\windows\system32\cmd as the window title.

In this case I was able to use AutoIt to kill the window instead of from a batch script.