# How do I close a command prompt after opening it?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to open a command prompt and then close it, it opens the command prompt but it doesn't close it, the error I get is:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified

```
import sys
import random
import subprocess
import os  

def x():
    subprocess.call('start',shell=True)
    os.system('taskkill /fi r"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"')
    #subprocess.run("exit")

x()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599655/how-to-close-a-cmd-window-using-python-2-7) might help.
I believe it is better practice to get the process ID, and call an `exit` or `kill` on that PID rather than calling it on the application itself.