# Windows Batch file - taskkill if window title contains text

Tags: windows, batch-file, process, cmd, taskkill

I want to write a simple batch file to kill a process that contains certain text in the window title. Right now I have:

```
taskkill /fi "Windowtitle eq XXXX*" /im cmd.exe
```

And that works, except what I want to do is use the wildcard both at the beginning AND end of the title. So something like:

```
taskkill /fi "Windowtitle eq \*X*" /im cmd.exe
```

But I tried this and it does not work. Is there something I'm missing or is this not possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, wildcards are not allowed at the start of the filter.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('
    tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v /fo:csv /nh 
    ^| findstr /r /c:".*X[^,]*$"
') do taskkill /pid %%a
```

This will retrieve the list of tasks, in csv and verbose format (that will include window title as the last field in the output).

The list is filtered by `findstr` with a regular expression that will search the indicated text (the `X`) in the last field.

If any line matches the filter, the `for` will tokenize it, retrieving the second field (the PID) that will be used in taskkill to end the process.

Comment: After searching for hours, this is by far the best method out there! Thank you, MC ND!

Comment: Finally a solution that worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

In the special case you have started the command window from a batch file yourself, you can specify the window title using the command

```
START MyWindowTitle c:/MyProcess.exe
```

That way it is easy to kill the process again using just

```
taskkill /fi "WindowTitle eq MyWindowTitle"
```

Comment: Nice ! this works.  Note: if your title has  "Administrator: " in front, see this answer here :  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948235/taskkill-window-spaces-in-its-title-name

Comment: Perfect and simple example. Thanks

Comment: You have to put double quotes around `MyWindowTitle` for the command to work

Answer (score 0):

A little more elaborate, but you can use:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims== " %%A in ('tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /fi "windowtitle eq MyWindowTi*"') do set "PID=%%A"
taskkill /F /T /PID !PID!
```