# How to close only one specific open docx file?

Tags: python, windows

I want to close only one window of a docx file opened in Microsoft Word between many others docx file opened, I am using `taskkill`,  but it  closes all docx files, because it closes the application by `WinWord.exe`. But what I want is just to close only one file between others, and keep others oppened.

The code is this:

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /f /im  WinWord.exe")
```

Comment: How are you going to decide which process should be killed?

Comment: I am using Image name....

Comment: You may be able to filter what taskkill does by using its `/fi` argument to "filter" what process it kills by specify the window's title. See accepted answer to [taskkill window spaces in its title name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948235/taskkill-window-spaces-in-its-title-name) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you opened the files but maybe try something like below?

```
f = open('foobar.docx', 'rb')
document = Document(f)
f.close()
```

Got it from just a little bit of random googling :P