# Why a working Title command in CMD.exe does not reflect in TASKLIST?

Tags: windows, cmd, taskkill, tasklist

SO is Windows 11. When I open a cmd window and then run the title command,
I can see the window title changing in the window tab. But then when I run tasklist, I get N/A in window title property.

Here is the sequence of commands:

```
cmd.exe
title aaa
tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /fo list
```

cmd is run from the Windows search bar (does not matter really, I think).

result:

```
Image Name:   cmd.exe
PID:          24088
Session Name: Console
Session#:     1
Mem Usage:    6,244 K
Status:       Unknown
User Name:    AzureAD\XXXXXXXX
CPU Time:     0:00:00
Window Title: N/A
```

Below a picture.
[image]

Does anyone knows why this is happening?.

I have tracked down this as a potential reason for a batch file failure using the TASKKILL command:
TASKKILL /F  /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq aaa" /IM cmd.exe

Comment: Screenshot looks like a Terminal process (aka OpenConsole.exe) not a window attached to cmd.exe.

Comment: I don't understand. It is run by typing cmd.exe in the windows search bar. It also does say that in the Image Name property.

Comment: Title's just a name for a window tab. It's not a program or process name. The system probably doesn't store it as a task name.

Comment: WINDOWTITLE is commonly used to filter for a taskkill command. Many examples can be found here in stackoverflow. Only one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948235/taskkill-window-spaces-in-its-title-name/25771089#25771089

Comment: Actually I just verified that the command TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq aaa" /T quoted in the question, does work. I don't know why including a flag to kill child processes (/T) might make the windows title filter work. The idea comes from what is suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51503315/11233327